# combining objects in logic editor

Tags: game-engine, physics, logic-bricks

[image: There I have added the door. How do I add the door handle?]In the game engine, I've created a door handle and door, and am trying to combine the physics in the logic editor so that when I left click on the door handle, it spins, meanwhile also swinging open the door at 120 degrees. To summarize my problem, when I select two objects, I can't get both under logic editor, and they end up having the same qualities. How do I separate them?

Comment: Could you explain closer, what you mean with "they have the same qualities"? Usually it shouldn't be a prolem to handle multiple objects with the same logic bricks.

Comment: @Quacksilber Ok, well I am having a problem with handling multiple objects within the same logic editor tab. What action do I need to choose to make the handle spin and what action do I need to make the door swing without a hinge?

Comment: Are the door and the handle rigged?

Comment: Do I need to work with the sensor for the objects in the physics column?

Comment: No, you can use any sensor on any object you like. It depends on how you would like to open the door. By standing near the door, and pressing a key? By klicking with the mouse on the handle? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

What your final result may look like:

[image]

---

You can link the logic-bricks of different objects if you select both of these objects in the 3d-view.

[image]

In my example, I use a mouse-over and a left-button sensor to detect a click on the handle. That goes to an and-controller, which is connected to both the armature of the door and the armature of the handle. Both armatures then play their animation.

Answer (score 1):

Inter-object connections are possible, but make your logic bricks really complex.

I assume you do not need very short reaction time on the mouse click. Therefore I suggest to communicate via messages. As additional benefit you can have any number of different door openers. (Button press, mouse click, joystick button, automatic door opener ...)

## Sensing when to open the door

The sole purpose of this logic is to send a message whenever the door should be opened. To differentiate the message from other message you set a meaningful subject such as "open door". Be aware when you have more than one door you should tell what door to open: "open door A" vs "open door B".

Example:

on door handle (of door A)

Sensor Mouse over 
Sensor Mouse left button 
Controller AND
Actuator Message subject "open door A"

## Opening the door

Your door and you handle or door A should both listen to a message "open door A".

handle:
Sensor Message subject "open door A"
Controller AND
Actuator Action ->play handle turning action.

door wing:
Sensor Message subject "open door A"
Controller AND
Actuator Action -> play wing opening action.

Both receive the message at the same time. This results in playing both actions at the same time. I guess this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine object physics with compound physics. You can assign/remove compounds at run-time with the `Parent` actuator, and turn on/off the compounds option accordingly.

**Tutorial**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6bY5Pro6U0